Joint report – Grouping Issue – unable to display in dashboard
we currently have a live dashboard with 20 panels/reports – however, one important panel/report we’re unable to display. It’s a joint report – with a pull thru ratio created. The ratio is correct and displays correct figure in joint report.
Joint report is made up of “Service/Maintenance Contract” and “Work Orders” – both reports are SFDC.com standard reports with no add-ons (eg. “and” or “with”).
However, we’re unable to display ratio pull thru figure in main dashboard as we need a “group” (Group Across Blocks) – which I believe is picking up the common fields between the 2x reports – we would have 10+ common exact fields (same SFDC ID backing codes in both reports). But they do not appear – we only get 3x options – 2x related to owner and 1x role. Owner for Service/Master Contract will always be EI Integration and work orders will always be Admin and Tech – hence – no entry will ever match of the hundred’s lines of data. Therefore, no graph in report “No results found”; hence, unable to display pull thru figure in main dashboard. The last group option is “role” – which directly relates to owner – same issue. Question, how do we get a graph/figure to be displayed in main dashboard from a joint report? We can do it in PowerBi and Excel but we want to use the Lightning SFDC function dashboard as the data live.
Help / assistance would be greatly appreciated, Regards Jayson (Australia)
